# How to UPDATE local variable inside a SELECT statement without printing the value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to `UPDATE` a variable inside a `SELECT` query wihtout showing on the table.

**Example**:

```
SET @X := 2;
SET @Y := 1;
SELECT @X * @Y AS "MULTIPLICATION", @X:=@X + 1;
```

But I don't want to print `@X:=@X+1`.

Comment: `SELECT ((@X := @X + 1) - 1) * @Y AS \`MULTIPLICATION\`` :)

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a subquery, then select what you want in the main query.

```
SELECT x * @y AS Multiplication
FROM (
    SELECT @x AS x, @x := @x + 1
) AS temp
```